CP Violation in Neutrinos Requied for Standard Model Baryogenesis
CP violation is required for baryogenesis in the standard model, but CP violation in the quark sector due to the CP violating phase in the CKM matrix is too small to account for it.
Following that, how much CP violation would need to be observed in neutrinos to account for baryogenesis in the standard model? What would the value of the Jarlskog invariant for neutrinos need to be, and what value of the CP violating phase in the PMNS matrix would allow this?
